# Best way of converting Oracle SQL query to JPA JPQL BETWEEN DATE/TIME

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, jpql

I am trying to run this SQL statement that finds a created entry between 6AM today to 6AM the next day. However I am having trouble finding a way of doing this with JPA JPQL. Any info will help, thanks.

**SQL STATEMENT**

```
    SELECT * FROM OTHER_ENTRY WHERE CREATED_DT 
    BETWEEN
    trunc(current_timestamp) + interval '6' hour
    AND 
    trunc(current_timestamp + 1)+ interval '6' hour;
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that "trunc", "interval", "hour" are not valid functions/keywords in JPQL? And JPQL is not SQL ...

Comment: Okay, I'll look at a different approach then to select between a specific time frame.